# In node.js how do you referance the directory below the current directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a `/custom_modules/db.js` and am trying to `require` it from `/routes/users.js` but am unsure of how to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should just use `../`
Example :

```
var db = require('../custom_modules/db.js');
```

Answer (score 2):

You use `./` to signify local directory that you are in, and `../` to go back a directory.  Therefore:

```
require('./../custom_modules/db');
```

Comment: @rdrey: Looks like you're right.  The answer @ OneOfOne posted seems to be more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Just insert a leading `/` to give an absolute path:

```
require('/custom_modules/db.jpg');
```

The rules for resolving modules path are detailed in the [modules](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) documentation.

Comment: after looking throught the modules documentation I saw `../` is exactly what I need

Comment: This actually would not work for me. I have to reference as `require('./custom_modules/db.js');`. I am using Windows.